# Why this form doesn't work? Javascript: number values in options from select input

Tags: javascript

I have this form that should show an error message if the value of Start time is higher than the one from End time, but if I select start at 8:00am and end at 4:00am it doesn't show an the error message, unless i put left zeros to numbers 1 to 9 (01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09), is like 1-9 without zeros were recognized as higher numbers than 10 - 48, why is that?

This work:

```
<script>
function execute_onclick()
{
    var result;

    if (document.forms[0].endtime.value >  document.forms[0].starttime.value)
    {
        result = "CORRECT";
    }
    else
    {
        result = "ERROR";
    }

    alert(result);

    return false;
}
</script>
<option value=01 >12:00 am</option>
<option value=02 >12:30 am</option>
<option value=03 >1:00 am</option>
<option value=04 >1:30 am</option>
<option value=05 >2:00 am</option>
<option value=06 >2:30 am</option>
<option value=07 >3:00 am</option>
<option value=08 >3:30 am</option>
<option value=09 >4:00 am</option>
<option value=10 >4:30 am</option>
```

This doesnt work:

```
<script>
function execute_onclick()
{
    var result;

    if (document.forms[0].endtime.value >  document.forms[0].starttime.value)
    {
        result = "CORRECT";
    }
    else
    {
        result = "ERROR";
    }

    alert(result);

    return false;
}
</script>
<option value=1 >12:00 am</option>
<option value=2 >12:30 am</option>
<option value=3 >1:00 am</option>
<option value=4 >1:30 am</option>
<option value=5 >2:00 am</option>
<option value=6 >2:30 am</option>
<option value=7 >3:00 am</option>
<option value=8 >3:30 am</option>
<option value=9 >4:00 am</option>
<option value=10 >4:30 am</option>
```

Comment: Because you are comparing strings of numbers, instead of actual numbers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing on the fly with `+` operator.

```
if (+document.forms[0].endtime.value > +document.forms[0].starttime.value)
```